# Ansible yum install rpm on remote server

Tags: ansible, yum

Really having a hard time with trying to install a rpm package that is on a server via ansible.
my script is

```
---
- hosts: "{{ hostlist | default('all') }}"
  vars:
    remote_path: "{{ remotepath | default('/usr/local/bin') }}"
    rpm_package: "{{ package }}"
  task:
    - name: install rpm package
      yum: name={{ remote_path }}/{{ rpm_package }}
      state: present
```

when I run it

```
ansible-pb pb-testyum1.yml -i --extra-vars "host=xxxdev01 remote_path=/usr/local/bin rpm_package=AvamarClient-linux-sles11-x86_64-18.2.100-134-RH7.rpm" --syntax-check

ERROR! the playbook: host=xxxdev01 remote_path=/usr/local/bin rpm_package=AvamarClient-linux-sles11-x86_64-18.2.100-134-RH7.rpm could not be found
```

the rpm is  AvamarClient-linux-sles11-x86_64-18.2.100-134-RH7.rpm
the location of the rpm is   /usr/local/bin

I cant understand the error

Comment: Please run with verbose logging by adding -vvv to the command and share more detailed logs

Comment: The rpm is located *on the remote host*? What if you add a `debug:` task to show the values of `remotepath` and `package`?

Comment: Can you please run with the stock `ansible-playbook` binary ? It looks like your entire extra var string is interpreted as a playbook filename (which is not found) and that might come from your custom alias/command `ansible-pb`. You are also passing an empty `-i` option which is normally not allowed. Remove the option or pass a valid inventory path.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use the `-i` (inventory) flag without specifying an inventory path.

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host | default('all') }}"
  vars:
    remote_path: "{{ remotepath | default('/usr/local/bin') }}"
    rpm_package: "{{ package }}"
  tasks:
    - name: install rpm package
      yum:
        name: "{{ remote_path }}/{{ rpm_package }}"
        state: present
```

Run:

```
ansible-playbook pb-testyum1.yml -e "host=xxxdev01 remote_path=/usr/local/bin rpm_package=AvamarClient-linux-sles11-x86_64-18.2.100-134-RH7.rpm" --syntax-check
```

Though this works, I recommend that you use invetory file (`-i`) instead of passing your host via extra-vars

Comment: Thats for that tip. Still trying to understand the syntax. When I run it if the -e i get the following error now                                                                                                            ERROR! playbooks must be a list of plays

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/pb-testyum1.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
  vars:
  ^ here

Comment: just double check your white spaces, you can also use -vvvv when running ansible-playbook to investigate. what version of ansible are you using

Comment: @goced btw, you can accept the answer if it solves your question